# Saving data in the database with Django

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to save my POST data to the database using the ModelForm but I couldn't make it go there for some reason.When I try to send the forms the page is redirecting me to the right place however the DB is still empty.I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

**forms.py**

```
class AddProblem(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = problem
        fields = ('lat','lng','email','importance','description','images')
```

**models.py**

```
class problem(models.Model):
    lat = models.BigIntegerField()
    lng = models.BigIntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True)
    importance = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    description = models.TextField()
    images = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')
    published = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**views.py**

```
def addproblem(request):
    temp_name = 'google_api/addproblem.html'
    form = AddProblem(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if(form.is_valid()):
            form.save()
            form = AddProblem()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Error")


    context =  {

    }

    return render(request, temp_name, context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('add/', views.addproblem, name='addproblem'),
]
```

**template**

```
<form action="/add/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Lat:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="lat" name="lat" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Lng:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="lng" name="lng" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Емайл</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Важност</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="importance" name="importance">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Описание на проблема.</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="description" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="form-group files">
        <label>Качете снимки</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="images" name="images">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit" value="Изпрати проблем">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Just in case, please note that 302 redirect _changes the method to GET,_ so if you depend on redirecting to a URL to post data to, don't.

Answer (score 0):

Views.py

```
    enter code here

    from django.views import generic
    from .models import Problem
    from .forms import AddProblem
    class CreateProblemView(generic.CreateView):
        model = Problem
        form_class = AddProblem
        success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
        template_name = 'google_api/addproblem.html'
```

forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import Problem
    class AddProblem(forms.ModelForm):
        model = Problem
            class Meta:
            model = Problem
            fields = '__all__'
```

template

```
    this add inside of form tag
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p }}
        after btn type submit 


    /form
```

Comment: I couldn't understand it...could you explain?

Comment: Read about the CSRF token. It may be the cause.

Comment: View based class is more easy

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it. So I needed to specify my encoding on my form so it became like that.

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then had to fix the **forms.py**

```
class AddProblem(forms.ModelForm):

    lat = forms.FloatField()
    lng = forms.FloatField()
    images = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
    class Meta:
        model = problem

        fields = ('lat','lng','email','importance','description','images')
```